# PHP | user management library with Facebook and Gmail authentication

Tags: php, facebook, user-management, google-account

I'm looking for a php library or a framework module:

- which enables user management (registration, login, password
  reminder),
- keeps the users in groups (readers, writers, moderators)
- and also integrates with Facebook and Google account authentication (one click
  login).

I came across libraries that either provide great user management or Fb/Gmail integration, but none of these that I found has both of these features.

I'm trying to build these in CodeIgniter but it seems super hard.

Does anyone know such a library? Thanks in advance.